# when click a <li> show <div> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to click a `<li>a</li>` then shows the `<div>1</div>`the html code :

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li class="on">a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>
<div>
    1
</div>
<div class="hide">
    2
</div>
<div class="hide">
   3
</div>
```

the css code is:

```
.hide{display:none;}
```

the js code is:

```
 window.onload=function(){
        var tab = document.getElementById("tabs"); 
        var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li"); 
        var div = tab.getElementsByTagName("div"); 

        for(i=0;i<li.length;i++){
            li[i].a=i;   
            click(li[i]);
        }

        function click(obj){
            obj.onclick = function(){
                for(n=0;n<li.length;n++){
                    div[n].className="hide";
                }

                div[i].className="";
            }

        }
    }
```

my idea is that I set a number for each `<li>` and when I click on this `<li>`, I make all the `<div>` disappear and only shows the `<div>` I want.

but the code doesn't work, it stucks of disappearing all the `<div>`

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: As your displayed code stands, you need a closing </div> for your <div id="tabs".

Otherwise var div = tab.getElementsByTagName("div"); won't work.

Answer (score 0):

ok,I figure it out. the last `div[i].className="";` should be `div[obj.a].className="";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<li onclick="showit(1)">a</li>
<li onclick="showit(2)">b</li>
<div id="div1" class="divs" style="visibility: hidden;">1</div>
<div id="div2" class="divs" style="visibility: hidden;">2</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function showit(n)
  {

     var x = document.getElementsByClassName("divs");
     var i;
     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
     }

     document.getElementById('div'+n).style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this. Javascript DOM only supports click() and onclick() for things that you *can click*.  That includes:

```
<input type="checkbox"...>
<input type="radio"...>
<input type="submit"...>
<input type="image"...>
<input type="reset"...>
<input type="submit"...>
<input type="button"...>
<input type="file"...>
<button...>
<a href=...>
<area>
```

I think some browsers will let you do this to input types "text", "password", and "textarea", but I wouldn't count on this: better to use onfocus() for these.

When I've wanted to do this in the past, I used link elements:
code :

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li class="on"><a href="#">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
</ul>
<div>
    1
</div>
<div class="hide">
    2
</div>
<div class="hide">
   3
</div>
```

You can use the CSS text-decoration= and color= properties to keep these from being visually marked as links (underline, different color, etc.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is incorrect, the DOM supports the `click` MouseEvent on any `HTMLElement`. You're thinking of the `click()` _method_, which is only on `HTMLInputElement`, `a`, and `button`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click.